# Own activity through Facebook app

Tags: facebook

is there some way to create an app for Facebook which will make own type of activity ? like eating, drinking, traveling.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Refer Custom stories in facebook graph api 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories/